# android onresume?

Tags: android, screen, onresume

I have an app that works perfectly fine after tons of testing, but when I exit out of the app (hit home screen) and let it sit for a while and come back to the app, I just have a black screen.  I have tried to reproduce this, but have been unable to, because it is only when I let the phone sit for a while...I have tried exiting out on each activity and even opening memory intensive apps on top of my app, then going back to my app, but it always works fine.  Unless I wait a while with the screen turned off then come back...black screen.   Any ideas?  Im not overriding onresume or onstart, should I be?

Comment: Are you using a SUrfaceView or similar view? i.e. is your screen a canvas?

Comment: Try that: override onResume to add something basic (a dialog or a Toast) and see if it comes up "on top" of the black screen, after resting for a while

Comment: It does hit onresume, i put a toast in there...so it hits onresume, but then just a black screen...and finally if it hit home or back it force closes

Comment: Too much work on UI thread, Please post your activity here so I can help you out with the specific solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this issue before but here are some tips you could try:

- Check your LogCat to see the results of what's happening after letting your phone sit for a while
- Are you able to reproduce this on the emulator?

Just curious, what type of phone are you testing this on? What Android version are you using?

Comment: EVO 4G 2.3.  Not sure about LogCat because like I said this only happens after letting it sit for a while.  I will try to let it sit connected to eclipse and check logcat.